# Bootstrap multiselect dynamically selecting dynamically added fields not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have my select:

```
<select id="fields_u" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

I appended the fields dynamically:

```
$('#fields_u').append(fields_html);
//or
$('#example-select').append($('<option>', {
    value: 'optionValue',
    text: 'optionText'
}));
```

Start the plugin:

```
$('#fields_u').multiselect();
```

Trying to select:

```
$('#fields_u').multiselect('select', ['0', '1'...]);
```

Not working...

This worked for me when the fields where on the DOM.

Is it a known issue?

**EDIT!**
Works, very sorry, silly me. I was sure you put the fields indexes in the select and not the fields names.

Comment: which is the plugin used

Comment: which version of multiselect you are using?

Comment: try with rebuild on click. $('#example-select').on('click', function() {
   $(this).multiselect('rebuild');
 });

Comment: bootstrap-multiselect.js Version 2.0

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/svv742r7/3/

Comment: using rebuild: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/svv742r7/4/

Comment: ok i am trying to figure out why my version doesnt work

Answer (score 4):

You need to refresh multiselect after appending the options dynamically:

```
$('#fields_u').multiselect('refresh');
```

Comment: not working, also tried : $('#example-select').multiselect('rebuild');